# Pandas groupby: ffill() + tail(1) in one call?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with three columns and timestamp index.

The columns are each indexed at slightly different times of day, and I want to unify the index to have one entry per day, labelled with the latest timestamp on that day.

The values of the output row should be the latest non-null value for that column on that date in the original data.

For example, given the following input:

```
                                  0         1         2
2021-05-11 14:00:00+00:00       NaN       NaN -1.339306
2021-05-11 21:15:00+00:00  0.636743 -0.102580       NaN
2021-05-12 14:00:00+00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
2021-05-12 21:15:00+00:00 -0.510190  0.041653       NaN
2021-05-13 14:00:00+00:00       NaN       NaN -1.821740
2021-05-13 21:15:00+00:00 -0.022989 -0.807958       NaN
2021-05-14 14:00:00+00:00       NaN       NaN -1.131520
2021-05-14 21:15:00+00:00 -0.014308       NaN       NaN
2021-05-17 14:00:00+00:00       NaN       NaN  1.400241
2021-05-17 21:15:00+00:00 -0.642951 -0.386940       NaN
```

The desired output would be:

```
                                  0         1         2
2021-05-11 21:15:00+00:00  0.636743 -0.102580 -1.339306
2021-05-12 21:15:00+00:00 -0.510190  0.041653       NaN
2021-05-13 21:15:00+00:00 -0.022989 -0.807958 -1.821740
2021-05-14 21:15:00+00:00 -0.014308       NaN -1.131520
2021-05-17 21:15:00+00:00 -0.642951 -0.386940  1.400241
```

The following expression implements the correct behaviour, given input `df`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.date, group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.ffill().tail(1))
```

Note that I'm using `group_keys=False` and `tail(1)` to preserve the original index labels in the output. The `.last()` aggregator does the right thing for the values, but it throws away the index.

The problem with the above is that `apply` is horrifyingly slow - taking 3 minutes on an input with with 15k rows.

I have realised that I can rewrite this as follows:

```
grouper = df.index.date
df.groupby(grouper).ffill().groupby(grouper).tail(1)
```

Which appears to have the exact same behaviour and is 4 orders of magnitude faster.

This is a reasonable enough solution for my immediate problem, but it feels *really* weird to have to do two successive `groupby` calls using the same grouper. I feel like there should be some way to use `GroupBy.agg` to do this, but everything I can find about `agg` seems to focus on applying aggregations to each column individually, rather than a chain of operations to all columns at once.

So my question is: is there another way of writing this operation which is at least as performant as the second solution (~10ms on a 15000x3 DataFrame), but doesn't require multiple calls to `groupby`?

Comment: It'll help if you have a sample input/output here which we can copy and test

Comment: Now added @ShubhamPeriwal

Comment: Try `groupby().ffill().drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you are looking for because you didn't provide input and expected output, but try:

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).agg([lambda g: g.ffill().tail(1)])
```

.agg(fun) let's you define complex aggregations in more general way.

Comment: This does not preserve the original index labels (regardless of the values of `group_keys` and `as_index`), and is considerably slower than the double-`groupby` solution.